# can I pass jenkins job parameters through github plugin

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-github-plugin

I'm trying to pass parameters through github hook to Jenkins with the help of Github plugin(in Jenkins).
The Jenkins job has several custom params - and I want github to trigger that job and setting those params.

In Github *repository/settings/hooks* there is the following URL hook:
*http://JENKINS-URL/github-webhook/*.

Is there a way to set these Jenkins job params from Github hook? (I cant install new plugins in Jenkins.. right now only Github plugin is installed)

Answer (score 0):

If you can curl your Jenkins instance from your GitHub Action script, [you can add multiple parameters to that `curl` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126080/6309).

There is an [appleboy/jenkins-action](https://github.com/appleboy/jenkins-action), but it [does not take any parameters](http://appleboy/jenkins-action/issues/2).