# How to trigger the build of a Jenkins pipeline using REST API with parameters in a POST request?

Tags: api, rest, jenkins, curl, jenkins-api

I made necessary setup to allow a Jenkins pipeline job to be triggered remotely using its REST API. I'm now testing build trigger using curl.

Builds are triggered properly but none of the build parameters are detected.

- Jenkins version is 2.210
- Apache HTTPd is used as a reverse-proxy
- OS is Centos 7.x
- User is configured (Active Directory user)
- User has relevant permissions (Global "Read", + Job
  "Read","Workspace" and "Build")
- User has an API_TOKEN generated
- Pipeline job has an authentication token defined

Build history shows that no parameter passed in POST are detected. Only those with a default value have it displayed instead of value passed in POST request.

```
curl -k -X POST https://<Jenkins URL>/job/<my job name>/buildWithParameters?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX --user <user>:<API TOKEN> --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"PARAM1": "true"},{"PARAM2": "foo"},{"PARAM3": "X.X.X.X"}]}'
```

I'm confused because this seemed to be the proper way to trigger a build using Jenkins API. How to properly trigger a pipeline job using the REST API and POST requests?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question:

[passing parameter to jenkins job through curl POST not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946863/passing-parameter-to-jenkins-job-through-curl-post-not-working#answer-61115039)

can you try the `curl -F` ?